# cURL --resolve issues

Tags: linux, unix, curl

I am trying to make a cURL request that resolves to a specific IP. From everything I've read, this looks syntactically correct to me but I am still seeing the 'could not resolve host error'. Can someone point me in the right direction? I'm seeing a variety of errors:

```
curl —-resolve e-dinar.io:443:42.81.15.75 "https://e-dinar.io"
IDN support not present, can't parse Unicode domains
* getaddrinfo(3) failed for —-resolve:80

curl —-resolve e-dinar.io:443:42.81.15.75 "https://e-dinar.io:443"
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host '—-resolve'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'e-dinar.io:443'

curl "https://e-dinar.io:443" —-resolve e-dinar.io:443:42.81.15.75 
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host '—-resolve'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'e-dinar.io:443'
```

Any thoughts where I am going wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong `-` in the curl command (`—`), change `—-` to `--`.
You have a hint in `curl` response here:

```
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host '—-resolve'
```

curl tries to get data from `—-resolve` host, it doesn't parse it as a command because of wrong `-`.

Comment: you are a bloody genius. my horrible eyesight!

Comment: where is this dash on the keyboard? I've just got the one on the key next to the 0 on my mac?

Comment: Yes, that's the one, I assume that your editor replaces minus sign with the longer one.